# JMeter: Seeing a sawtooth graph instead of a smooth one (constant load)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am using JMeter to load test my application. This is how my thread group configuration looks like:

[image]

I am expecting to hit the application with 200 threads (requests) and keep up that load for 30 minutes.

I am using 5 throughput controllers which use percentage executions and each HTTP request (under each controller) uses a specific percentage (totals to a 100).

I use the non-GUI mode to start the test and output the results to a csv. When I plot this though (using Kibana), I see a graph which looks like this

[image]

I see a peak and drop every 5 minutes. I am expecting to see uniform load across the 30 minutes I am running my test. Any idea why this is happening ? Is there something wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: If the graph shows number of hits/requests the server process might get congested resulting in longer execution times and less hits until the congestion clears, more requests get through and the cycle repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into "Loop Count" of `1` in your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) I don't think your tests lasts 30 minutes, my expectation is that it takes **seconds** (or whatever time is needed to execute all your [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) with 200 threads)

So tick `Forever` box or set "Loop Count" to `-1` and re-run your test.

More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)

Comment: I did try "forever". I still see the same saw tooth graph. The test runs long, but the graph pattern remains :(

Comment: It might indicate a bottleneck either in JMeter (i.e. it does [garbage collection](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) due to lack of heap space) or in SUT. Make sure you're following recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure]) article and ensure that both JMeter and SUT have enough headroom using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon)

Comment: Interesting, that could be true. Lemme give those links a read, thanks !